# Filtering three level nested array in javascript

Tags: javascript, angular

I’m trying to filter an array by the third level nested array value. I tried using `.filter`. The array format is shown below for example. I need to filter menuItems based on role.

```js
const menuItems = [{
    title: 'inventory',
    submenu: [{
        title: 'GRN',
        role: ['admin']
      },
      {
        title: 'purchase order',
        role: ['user']
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    title: 'sales-invoice',
    submenu: [{
        title: 'invoice ',
        role: ['admin']
      },
      {
        title: 'invoice-list',
        role: ['user']
      },
    ]
  },
]
```

A varible role is defined

```
var role=['admin']
```

I tried to filter using the following code. But i couldn't get the result

```js
const result = menuItems.filter(menu => {
  if (menu.submenu) {
    menu.submenu.filter(submenu => {
      return this.role.some(val => (submenu.role.indexOf(val) !== -1))
    })
  }
})
```

Comment: Is ```main.submenu``` a typo? I think it will be ```menu.submenu```.

Comment: Also, `this.role` should be `submenu.role`?

Comment: No.. role is defined outside

Comment: Do you want to filter anything in that array dynamically or just role?

Comment: Are you trying to filter all of the submenu items by role? If so, is this a single role or multiple roles?

Comment: I want to filter the whole array based on the role type. A variable role is defined outside of the function.  Based on the value of that variable i need to filter the result

Comment: user may have single or multiple roles

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for? Based on the `someRole` string, it will return all `submenu` items with that role.

```js
const menuItems = [
    {
        title: 'inventory',
        submenu: [
            {
                title: 'GRN',
                role: ['admin']
            },
            {
                title: 'purchase order',
                role: ['user']
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        title: 'sales-invoice',
        submenu: [
            {
                title: 'invoice ',
                role: ['admin']
            },
            {
                title: 'invoice-list',
                role: ['user']
            },
        ]
    }
]

let someRole = 'user'

for(const menu in menuItems) {
    const filteredItems = menuItems[menu].submenu.filter(item => item.role.includes(someRole))
    menuItems[menu].submenu = filteredItems
}

console.log(menuItems)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to disable all the options for the user that are visible for the admin.

```js
var menuItems = [{
    title: 'inventory',
    submenu: [{
        title: 'GRN',
        role: ['admin']
      },
      {
        title: 'purchase order',
        role: ['user']
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    title: 'sales-invoice',
    submenu: [{
        title: 'invoice ',
        role: ['admin']
      },
      {
        title: 'invoice-list',
        role: ['user']
      },
    ]
  },
]

const filterMenu = (menuItems, targetRoles) => menuItems.map((item) => ({
  ...item, 
  submenu: item.submenu.filter(({role}) => 
    targetRoles.reduce((acc, val) => acc + Number(!role.includes(val)), 0))
}))

console.log(filterMenu(menuItems, ['admin']))
```

This might be problematic if you were to put admin and user into the roles array.

Comment: User may have more than one role.That's why array used instead of string

Comment: I have edited the function. I still think putting both roles in the role array in the submenu will cause trouble though. You need to think of how you want to handle this situation.

Answer (score -1):

This will work if global `role` and `role` in **submenu** object are arrays.

```
const menuItems = [
  {
    title: "inventory",
    submenu: [
      {
        title: "GRN",
        role: ["admin"]
      },
      {
        title: "purchase order",
        role: ["user"]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    title: "sales-invoice",
    submenu: [
      {
        title: "invoice ",
        role: ["admin"]
      },
      {
        title: "invoice-list",
        role: ["user"]
      }
    ]
  }
];

var role = ["admin"];

const result = menuItems.filter(({ submenu }) => {
  if (!submenu) return false;

  return submenu.some(({ role: menuItemRoles }) =>
    menuItemRoles.some(menuItemRole => role.includes(menuItemRole))
  );
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: this would disable the whole menu. classic

Comment: What is **disable the whole menu** means?

Comment: To be technical, your thing is not filtering anything but the general idea is that you use filter at top level, meaning if one of the sub menu items has the role you return true. But if you look, you should leave all the menu intact and just filter what is required. Why do I see a user menu showing when you filter for admin? You return either the full sub menu or nothing, you should return the parts of the sub menu that meet the filter criteria.

Comment: The key is to use map at top level and not filter. You want to return the same me u back but filter some of the options of the sub menu.